# File upload pdf issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, pdf, file-upload

I'm using carrierwave, minimagick and Rails 4.

I have a FileUploader that looks like:

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

   version :thumb, if: :image? do
      process :resize_to_limit => [50, 50]
   end

   version :thumb, unless: :image? do
      process :cover    
      process :resize_to_fill => [50, 50, Magick::NorthGravity]
      process :convert => 'png'
   end

   protected

   def image?(new_file)
      new_file.content_type.start_with? 'image'
   end

   def cover 
      manipulate! do |frame, index|
         frame if index.zero?
      end
   end

end
```

If pdf's are uploaded, I'm trying to create a thumb png version of the first page. If images are uploaded, I'm resizing and saving a thumb version of that.

I get the error: `NameError (uninitialized constant FileUploader::Magick)` now, though it works when I take away the block with the `unless`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Magick::NorthGravity` constant is part of `rmagick` gem (see [here](https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/blob/master/ext/RMagick/rmenum.c#L800)), not part of `mini_magick`.